# How to Swagger Annotate a Spring GET @RequestMapping having a complex Object

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, swagger, swagger-ui

The issue is that I have a complex Object as Request Param for a GET-Request and after I place the Swagger Annotations inside the Object. The Swagger UI shows that the entry param is a body in which i have to place the Params.

```
 body: {
      "modelId": 0,
      "makeId": 0
    }
```

My REST controller looks like this

```
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/model")
  public SearchModelsResponse searchModels(
      @ApiParam(value = "Search for something",
          required = true) final ModelSearch search) {...}
```

And the Request object

```
public class ModelSearch {

  @ApiParam(value = "Something important)", required = true)
  private Long modelId;

  @ApiParam(value = "Something else important)", required = false)
  @Nullable
  private Long makeId;

  ....
  }
```

Is there a Way to Annotate it correctly so Swagger shows it as correctly as Request Parameters and not as a body construct ?

Comment: Object as request parameter ? I don't think so. Only primitives are supported as request parameters.

Comment: Well it works well on Spring side and Jackson has no issues in the deserialising process. The only thing that breaks is swagger.

Comment: Exactly I meant It is not supported by swagger. In Spring, you can have whatever you want.

Comment: Is this kind of Implementation common on GET methods ? I saw some implementations also with an object to deserialize instead of primitives.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

OK the solution in this kind of scenario is to manually define the Parameters, this is possible with the `@ApiImplicitParam` annotation.

So as result this looks like this.

```
  @ApiImplicitParams({
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "modelId", value = "this is modelId", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query"),
    @ApiImplicitParam(name = "makeId", value = "this is makeId", required = true, dataType = "string", paramType = "query")
  })
  @RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET, value = "/model")
  public SearchModelsResponse searchModels(
      final ModelSearch search) {...}
```

It's not a beautifull solution since I actually want swagger to interprete my code but the result gives the option to show it as request parameters not as a body construct.